# poco objects in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, poco

I'm used to language that have `class`, `interface` etc. So I need to get use to how things are done in Javascript and NodeJS. One of those things is `Entity` or `Model` classes.

Is that needed in Javascript?

Suppose I have to pass a simeple poco object to a class in NodeJS; Is it common to define a poco class for that? For example, I'm writing a Router module and I want to pass a `Route` object to my `Router` class.

route.js

```
var route = {
  routeUrl: null,
  controller: null,
  action: null
}
```

Then somewhere in my code I want to add a `route`.

```
var route = new route();
route {
  routeUrl: '/users',
  controller: 'usersController',
  action: 'index'
}

router.addRoute(route);
```

Or shouldn't I waste my time on poco classes like my `route` class? SHould I just do something like this?

```
router.addRoute({
  routeUrl: '/users',
  controller: 'usersController',
  action: 'index'
});
```

The thing is, I'm used to languages that have a `class`, `interface` etc. With Type Hinting in their parameters. And because of that it's easier for a developer to know what kind of object he needs and what properties can be set on a simple poco class.

But what is common in NodeJS for this kind of situation?

Comment: Your `route` example wouldn't work because you can only use `new` on functions. There is no single answer to this question. 95% of APIs are perfectly happy to be passed a plain object like in your last code example. If you want to add organization to your code for types that you reuse a lot, you might consider using constructors and prototypes for those.

Comment: Being "used to" something is a pretty harmful state of mine in my opinion - what _problems_ did POCOs solve for you in these languages? Can you identify these problems in your current work in JavaScript? (If not - where did it go?) If you can identify these problems - would adding "plain ol'" objects address these issues here?

Comment: I might look into TypeScript, which has classes, types, etc, and then is translated into JS

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well it's basically the intellisense that you get out of it. I know that this is more a IDE feature, but this is possible because the parameters are typed. Im missing that in JS. You ***"have to know"*** what kind of object you need to put in. You cant always tell from the params. Which you can in Java or .net for example

Comment: @w00 good IDEs like WebStorm or editors with TernJS enabled will gladly  let you know when a property is on an object. If you miss the typing you can consider Facebook's flowtype, Google's jscomment annotations or TypeScript